# How to extract Close price of currency pair from Quantmod library

Tags: r

This is what my code looks like, could anyone please suggest how can I extract only Close price of the currency pair

```
library(quantmod)  
from <- c("USD", "EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "THB", "KRW")   
to <- c("CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY", "CNY" )   
getSymbols(paste0(from, to, "=X"), from = "2020-01-01", to = "2022-01-01")   
myRetData <- lapply(paste0(from, to, "=X"), function(sym) {coredata(na.omit(getSymbols(sym, from="2020-01-01", to="2022-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE)))})
```

for example, I'd tried `myRetData$KRWCNY=X.Close` but the result is shown below

> Error: object 'X.Close' not found

Answer (score 0):

You have nested lists. So, first, you have to index the correct list and then the column inside the list. In your case the sixth list and fourth column. You can see the structure of your list by running the command `glimpse(myRetData)` from package `dplyr`. For the selection of the specific column, run the following command:

```
data <- data.frame(`KRWCNY=X.Close` = myRetData[[6]][,4])
```